# Rails: How do I define an association extension in a module that gets included in my AR model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a `Blockable` module that contains associations and methods to be included in a few other `ActiveRecord` classes.

Relevant code:

```
module Blockable
  def self.included(base)
    base.has_many :blocks
  end
end
```

I want to add an association extension. The usual syntax (ie when I'm not defining the association in a module) is like this:

```
# definition in Model < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :blocks do
  def method_name
    ... code ...
  end
end

# usage
Model.first.blocks.method_name
```

This syntax doesn't work when used in the module which is included in the AR model. I get an `undefined method 'method_name' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xa16b714>`.

Any idea how I should go about defining an association extension in a module for inclusion in other AR classes?

Comment: Your module looks fine, it just seems like you're calling it incorrectly. `Model.blocks` shouldn't work. You're calling it on an object and not an instance of that object.

Try `Model.first.blocks.method_name`.

Comment: Sorry, fail example by me. I have been trying to call it on an instance - I've updated my question to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh, I suck.

I had an unrelated bug that was causing the association extension to break.

I have verified that both my original method and Xavier Holt's method work under Rails 3.0.3:

```
self.included(base)
  base.has_many :blocks do 
    def method
      ...
    end
  end
end

# OR

self.included(base)
  base.class_eval do 
    has_many :blocks do
      def method
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Rails 3 has some helper methods for this.  This example is from [The Rails 3 Way, 2nd Edition](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780132480345/advanced-active-record/ch09lev1sec10):

```
module Commentable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I have something similar working in my Rails code (2.3.8) at the moment.  I used `base.class_eval` rather than `base.has_many`:

```
module Blockable
    self.included(base)
        base.class_eval do
            has_many :blocks do
                def method_name
                    # ...stuff...
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Whew - that was a lot of spacebarring...

Anyway, that works for me - hopefully it'll work for you, too!

Comment: Thanks for the look-in and giving me another method to try. Turns out I'd screwed up elsewhere and both approaches work!